# My SQL parameter is unable to represent long text in query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
TextBox3.Text = "FD&C Yellow No 6 /E110 Sunset Yellow Lake 35";

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT S.Qty AS Qty, S.Units, S.Packing, S.Lot, S.Price, S.PackSize, S.Location FROM Product P, Stock S, Lot L WHERE P.Product = L.ProductID and S.Lot=L.Lot and P.Product = @Pro ;";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pro", TextBox3.Text);
```

The query is not getting values although it should do. This problem happens because the text is long because it works with shorter texts even though they have the same special characters like & /.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the exact type of the Product column in the database table?

Comment: One possible problem is using the "old" join syntax where you include multiple tables in the "from" clause. Instead, use explicit join clauses. This prevents a lot of problems that occur with the "old" syntax.

Comment: This is not a long text. There is no possibility that this text represents a problem for the database engine when passed as parameter. Instead I will look for blank spaces not exactly the same as the value on the database table. Did you try to use a LIKE with a search for "FD&C%" to see if it returns the required record?

Comment: Did you try running the same query in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Product column in DB is nvarchar max.